# HasOneThrough Relationship on different connections

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have these models

```
class Device extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $connection = 'traccar';
    
   public function vehicle()
   {
       //Code I need
   }
}

class Vehicle extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $connection = 'mysql';
  
}

class VehicleDevice extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $connection = 'mysql';
}
```

as you can see the Device is in a tracar database and the reset of the models are in the MySQL connection.

How do I write a hasOneThrough relationship for the devices to the vehicle?
I am getting an error that says

```
Table 'tracar.vehicles' doesn't exist (Connection: traccar, SQL: select * from `tc_devices` where exists (select * from `vehicles` inner join `vehicle_devices` on `vehicle_devices`.`id` = `vehicles`.`vehicle_device_id` where `tc_devices`.`id` = `vehicle_devices`.`device_id`))'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Device extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $connection = 'traccar';
    
    public function vehicle()
    {
        return $this->hasOneThrough(
            Vehicle::class,
            VehicleDevice::class,
            'device_id', // Foreign key on the VehicleDevice model
            'id', // Foreign key on the Vehicle model
            'id', // Local key on the Device model
            'vehicle_device_id' // Local key on the VehicleDevice model
        );
    }
}
```

By defining this relationship, you can access the associated `Vehicle` model from a Device instance using the vehicle property. For example:

```
$device = Device::find(1);
$vehicle = $device->vehicle; // Retrieve the associated Vehicle model
```

Comment: I still get the error table or view not found

Comment: both schemas(connections) should be in the same server.